# How to res.render/send a variable after a redirect?

Tags: node.js, express, redirect, express-router

I want to send a message variable that says something like succeeded or failed wihtout the use of passport or sessions.

When it fails I can just do this:

```
res.status(401).render('register', {
    message: 'Your username/email or password is incorrect.'
})
```

So I was thinking this was possible:

```
res.redirect('/');
res.render('', { message: 'Login success.'});
```

But it turns out it isn't:

```
Error: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

Are there any simple sollutions?

I tried making a router.get('/message/redirect :route') but I realised I ran into the same problem there too.

Comment: What do you mean by send a message? Who will receive that message? How this message will be processed?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I meant to dispay it in ejs/html file like this: `<% if (locals.message) { %>
        <div class="message">
            <h4 class="message-text"><%= message %></h4>
        </div>
    <% } %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redirecting before rendering. So the render method can't send headers because you have already redirected them. You need to call either redirect or render, not both at once. you can do it like this.

```
res.render('/', { message: 'Login success.'});
```

remove this line

```
res.redirect('/');
```

In your EJS file just call `<%= message %>` to access the message. There is a better way of dealing with confirmation/error messages. Use Flash.

```
npm install express-flash
```

Then before rendering, call the flash. Flash takes two arguments, a name of the message and the message itself, Like this

```
req.flash("MessageName", "Login success");
res.redirect(pathName);
```

Make sure to use flash

```
const flash = require('express-flash');
app = express();
app.use(flash());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.MessageName= req.flash("MessageName");
    next();
});
```

To access the message in EJS file just call `<%= MessageName %>`

Here is sample from my code:
In the server file:

```
req.flash("error", "Something went wrong");
res.redirect('back');
```

In the EJS file:

```
<div class="flash">
    <% if(error && error.length > 0){ %> 
        <div class="flash_error">
            <h1 class="flash_error--text"><%= error %></h1> 
        </div>
    <% } %> 
</div>
```

[Read this for more information](https://snyk.io/advisor/npm-package/express-flash)

Comment: Yeah I got that but I want to display the message after the redirect has taken place. If it is even possible...

Comment: I have updated the post. Hope this is what you want